# Why does my update to a Listbox in a while loop with PySimpleGUI end up in my program hanging?

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, pysimplegui

So, I am building a little Python program to do some cost and throughput calculations for me. Keep in mind, I am a Python novice and completely new to PySimpleGUI with this project. I am specifically concerned with why, in the code below, line 59 (`thruput_window['LISTBOX'].update(prompt)` within the `update_values()` function) is causing the program to hang? I would think it should update with the indicated string, and continue on through the while loop, but instead it just stalls out, and doesn't even update the Listbox element with `prompt`. Any ideas?

Thanks for the help, and apologies for the long code block; I don't post on here often, and wasn't sure how much to include so I just posted the whole thing.

```
# Throughput & Cost of Ownership Calculations
# Import necessary libraries
import PySimpleGUI as sg


# Define functions
def import_values():
    mylines = []
    myvalues = []
    with open(r'throughput_variables.txt', 'r') as file:
        for myline in file:
            mylines.append(myline.rstrip('\n'))
    for element in mylines:
        start = element.find(':') + 2
        end = len(element)
        value = int(element[start:end])
        myvalues.append(value)
    return myvalues


def import_variables():
    mylines = []
    myvariables = []
    with open(r'throughput_variables.txt', 'r') as file:
        for myline in file:
            mylines.append(myline.rstrip('\n'))
    for element in mylines:
        variable = element[:element.find(':')]
        myvariables.append(variable)
    return myvariables


def display_file():
    mylines = []
    myfile = []
    with open(r'throughput_variables.txt', 'r') as file:
        for myline in file:
            mylines.append(myline.rstrip('\n'))
    for element in mylines:
        myfile.append(element)
    return myfile


def update_values():
    Qtable1 = "What is the total recipe 1 time? \n"
    Qtable2 = "What is the total recipe 2 time? \n"
    Qtable3 = "What is the total recipe 3 time? \n"
    Qcleaner = "What is the total recipe time for the cleaner? \n"
    Qwts4 = "How long does it take to unload? \n"
    Qwetbot = "How long does it take the robot to handle? \n"
    myprompts = [Qtable1, Qtable2, Qtable3, Qcleaner, Qwts4, Qwetbot]
    myvariables = import_variables()
    myvalues = ['','','','','','']
    k = 0
    thruput_window['USER-INPUT'].bind('<Return>', '_Enter')
    with open(r'throughput_variables.txt', 'w+') as file:
        while k < 6:
            prompt = [myprompts[k]]
            thruput_window['LISTBOX'].update(prompt)
            if thruputEvent == 'USER-INPUT' and '_Enter':
                myvalues.append(thruputValues['USER-INPUT'])
                thruput_window['LISTBOX'].update([prompt[k],myvalues[k]])
                file.write(myvariables[k] + ": " + myvalues[k] + "\n")
                k = k + 1
    return import_values()


def calc_thruput(myvalues):
    t1_time = myvalues[0]
    t2_time = myvalues[1]
    t3_time = myvalues[2]
    cleaner_time = myvalues[3]
    wts4_transfer_time = myvalues[4]
    wet_bot_time = myvalues[5]
    denominator = max(t1_time, t2_time, t3_time) - min(t1_time, t2_time, t3_time) + \
                  max(t3_time, cleaner_time) + wts4_transfer_time + wet_bot_time
    numerator = 3600
    thruput = numerator / denominator
    return round(thruput, 2)


# Setup the home screen GUI
sg.theme('Dark2')
fnt = ('Gadugi', 20)
layout = [[sg.Text("What would you like to calculate? \n", font=('Gadugi', 40))],
          [sg.Button("Cost of Ownership")],
          [sg.Button("Throughput")],
          [sg.Button("Exit")]]
# Create the window
main_window = sg.Window("Operations Estimations", layout, margins=(400, 250), font=fnt)

# Create an event loop
while True:
    event, values = main_window.read()
    if event == "Throughput":
        with open(r'throughput_variables.txt', 'r') as file:
            content = display_file()
        layout = [[sg.Text("Do these times look correct, or would you like to append? ", font=('Gadugi', 30))],
                  [sg.Text("All times are in seconds. ", font=fnt)],
                  [sg.Listbox(values=content, size=(70, 10), key='LISTBOX')],
                  [sg.Input(size=(25, 1), enable_events=True, key='USER-INPUT')],
                  [sg.Button("Correct")],
                  [sg.Button("Append")],
                  [sg.Button("Go Back")]]
        thruput_window = sg.Window("Throughput Calculator", layout, margins=(325, 150), font=fnt)

        while True:
            thruputEvent, thruputValues = thruput_window.read()

            if thruputEvent == "Correct":
                answer = ["Throughput = ", str(calc_thruput(import_values())) + " microns/hour"]
                thruput_window['LISTBOX'].update(answer)
            if thruputEvent == "Append":
                answer = ["Throughput = ", str(calc_thruput(update_values())) + " microns/hour"]
                thruput_window['LISTBOX'].update(answer)
            elif thruputEvent == "Go Back" or event == sg.WIN_CLOSED:
                break
        thruput_window.close()
    # End program if user presses Exit or closes the window
    if event == "Exit" or event == sg.WIN_CLOSED:
        break
main_window.close()
```

Edit: So I took your advice on getting rid of the nested windows (thanks), and just set up a right column that appears when the appropriate selection in the left column is clicked. But even though it's much simpler now, I am never able to even enter the `Correct` or `Append` loops now - what am I missing? I'm sure it's something simple I am overcomplicating.

```
# Setup the overall GUI font and theme, column structure, and window layout
sg.theme('Dark2')
fnt = ('Gadugi', 20)
left_column = [[sg.Text("What would you like to calculate? \n", font=('Gadugi', 30))],
               [sg.Button("Throughput"),
               sg.Button("Cost of Ownership"),
               sg.Button("Exit")]]
right_column = [[sg.Text("Do these times look correct, or would you like to append? ", font=('Gadugi', 30), key='HEADER', visible=False)],
                  [sg.Text("All times are in seconds. ", font=fnt, key='WARNING', visible=False)],
                  [sg.Listbox(values=[], size=(70, 10), key='LISTBOX', visible=False)],
                  [sg.Input(size=(25, 1), enable_events=True, key='USER-INPUT', visible=False)],
                  [sg.Button("Correct", key='CORRECT', visible=False),
                   sg.Button("Append", key='APPEND', visible=False)]]
layout = [[sg.Column(left_column),
          sg.VSeparator(),
          sg.Column(right_column)]]
window = sg.Window("Operations Estimations", layout, font=fnt)

# Create an event loop
while True:
    event, values = window.read()
    if event == "Exit" or event == sg.WIN_CLOSED:
        break
    if event == "Throughput":
        window['HEADER'].update(visible=True)
        window['WARNING'].update(visible=True)
        window['LISTBOX'].update(visible=True)
        window['USER-INPUT'].update(visible=True)
        window['CORRECT'].update(visible=True)
        window['APPEND'].update(visible=True)
        with open(r'throughput_variables.txt', 'r') as file:
            content = display_file()
        window['LISTBOX'].update(content)
    if event == "Correct":
        window['LISTBOX'].update(["TEST"])
        print('This is working')
        # answer = ["6EZ Throughput = ", str(calc_thruput(import_values())) + " microns/hour"]
        # window['LISTBOX'].update(answer)
    if event == "Append":
        window['USER-INPUT'].bind('<Return>', '_Enter')
        answer = ["Throughput = ", str(calc_thruput(update_values())) + " microns/hour"]
        window['LISTBOX'].update(answer)

window.close()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`update_values` called in the event "Append" of thruput_window.

In function `update_values`, you do something wrong

- bind return key to element `'USER-INPUT'`, binding should be done right after your thruput_window finalized, then while loop to read event.

```py
thruput_window = sg.Window("Throughput Calculator", layout, margins=(325, 150), font=fnt, finalize=True)    # Add option `finalize=True`
thruput_window['USER-INPUT'].bind('<Return>', '_Enter')
```

- update element again and again, should be better to update once. Including update in the event "Append" of thruput_window, total 13 times, but only last one shown.

```py
    with open(r'throughput_variables.txt', 'w+') as file:
        while k < 6:
            prompt = [myprompts[k]]
            thruput_window['LISTBOX'].update(prompt)
            if thruputEvent == 'USER-INPUT' and '_Enter':
                myvalues.append(thruputValues['USER-INPUT'])
                thruput_window['LISTBOX'].update([prompt[k],myvalues[k]])
                file.write(myvariables[k] + ": " + myvalues[k] + "\n")
                k = k + 1
```

- Wrong event handling, it is under event "Append", so following if will be always False. It should be in while loop for thruput_window, so a new thruput_window.read() to get the event, without `read`, no new thruputEvent and thruputValues.

```py
if thruputEvent == 'USER-INPUT' and '_Enter':
```

- Event from binding of element with str key, the event will be key+'_Enter', so shoule be like this

```py
if thruputEvent == 'USER-INPUT_Enter':
```

Nested window or while-loop make you code complex, it is preferred to use another function to handle your second window, maybe like this

```py
import PySimpleGUI as sg

def function():

    sg.theme("DarkGrey3")
    layout = [
        [sg.Text()],
        [sg.Input(key='INPUT')],
        [sg.Button('OK'), sg.Button('Cancel')],
        [sg.Text()],
    ]
    window = sg.Window('POPUP', layout, finalize=True, modal=True)
    window['INPUT'].bind("<Return>", "_RETURN")

    while True:

        event, values = window.read()
        if event in (sg.WINDOW_CLOSED, 'Cancel'):
            value = None
            break
        elif event == 'OK':
            value = values['INPUT']
            break

    window.close()
    return value

font = ('Courier New', 11)
sg.theme('DarkBlue3')
sg.set_options(font=font)

layout = [
    [sg.Button("Get Input")],
    [sg.Text("",size=(80, 1), key='TEXT')],
]
window = sg.Window('Title', layout, finalize=True)

while True:

    event, values = window.read()
    if event == sg.WINDOW_CLOSED:
        break
    elif event == 'Get Input':
        value = function()
        if value is None:
            window['TEXT'].update('[Cancel]')
        else:
            window['TEXT'].update(value)

window.close()
```

[image]

[Update]

For key of a Button, it is defined by

- if there's an option `key` defined
- if there's an option `k` defined
- use button_text if not duplicate in layout
- use `str(element.Key) + str(window.UniqueKeyCounter))` if duplicate

Here, you defined key of buttons as 'CORRECT' and 'APPEND', an the event is always the key of the element, not the button_text. that's why you never go into the event handlers of 'Correct' and 'Append'.

Comment: So I took your advice on getting rid of the nested windows (thanks), and just set up a right column that appears when the appropriate selection in the left column is clicked. But even though it's much simpler now, I am never able to even enter the `Correct` or `Append` loops now - what am I missing? I'm sure it's something simple I am overcomplicating. Edited code is in the main post now.

Comment: Update as above